# Can I use a USB stick for a normal install? (to get platform adaptability)

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, live-usb, live-cd

So I know I can make a persistent LiveUSB whereby there would be anywhere up to 4GB (I think that's the max) of persistent storage for downloads, etc.

I am asking the opposite, in a sense. I'd like to configure a USB install to have the platform adaptability that a Live OS offers while fully utilizing the 120GB of space I have.

In essence I'm hoping to have a boot up install that reconfigures most/all the hardware/drivers as necessary every boot as I'd like to be able to boot off of it on nearly any machine. (*Within reason - they will all be 64-bit*)

The biggest gripe with doing multi-platform booting is the video driver stuff. Sometimes the system I'm booting off of is AMD, sometimes Nvidia, sometimes Intel.

Alternatively, a usable answer may be a way to better configure the LiveUSB setup for more storage utilization and customization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem whatsoever! (I've got a USB disk just like that but I've never tried anything but BIOS machines, as I rarely encounter UEFI machines and if I meet one, I put them in BIOS mode and revert back when I leave)

Procedure is exceedingly simple:

1. Buy a decent USB 3.0 [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) USB disk. These are normally advertised as 200-300 Mbps USB 3.0 disks, but your mileage may vary. Read the specs

   **Why?** SLC is vastly superior in speed to MLC or TLC drives and lasts about 4-12 times longer.  This outweighs the cost of these things... (2-3 times as expensive as other "fast" USB disks, 3-4 times as expensive as a low-end one)
2. Use Lubuntu (in your case: 64-bit)

   **Why?** Lubuntu is the most compatible of all of the Ubuntu family and you're not going to use this as a high-end server, so Lubuntu will be snazzy even on a 1GB USB 2.0 machine. I use the 32-bit version with PAE extensions forced as I run this thing on a variety of hardware (mainly to resurrect Windows machines, but I've been told already to wipe the F|@#§g Windows and install this nifty, fast, free OS!)
3. Install like you would install any other machine, but treat the SLC as a simple hard disk and install `grub`, `swap`, `/` and `/home`.
4. Optimise `fstab` as you would for [an SSD drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives#Tips_for_Maximizing_SSD_Performance)

   **Why 3+4?**  Obviously **;-)** you basically *have an SSD on a stick!*
5. Set the `sysctl.conf` parameters as follows:

   ```
   # Prevent USB wear out due to excessive swap usage.
   # Only start swapping when the memory is 90% full
   vm.swappiness = 10

   # This percentage value controls the tendency of the kernel to reclaim
   # the memory which is used for caching of directory and inode objects.
   #
   # At the default value of vfs_cache_pressure=100 the kernel will attempt to
   # reclaim dentries and inodes at a "fair" rate with respect to pagecache and
   # swapcache reclaim.  Decreasing vfs_cache_pressure causes the kernel to prefer
   # to retain dentry and inode caches.
   #
   # Basically, once something is swapped it's probably not immediately needed
   # any more, so increase the kernel's resistance a bit more trying to build up
   # a large cache again.
   vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 75

   # Good to improve sequential reads (stop stuttering background music)
   # Can also be implemented per disk using udev rules
   # in KB, so only 3MB lost, so who cares nowadays?
   vm.max-readahead=2048
   vm.min-readahead=1024
   ```

   **Why?**  Read the comments above...
6. Install as many command-line tools as you want, but stay away from huge memory-hungry programs as you won't know what kind of machine you'll be running this on.  (OK: I confess: I've got LibreOffice running, but that's about it.  Nu MySQL, no GIMP, no 3D-rendering, ...)
7. Stay away from any proprietary modules (aka drivers), just standard Linux kernel modules... And these are extremely good at adapting to their environment! They're like mongrels: they'll eat anything, drink anything and ... well, whatever. ;-) It just works!

### That's it!

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: What part of this gives me boot up adapting? My main concern is video driver compatibility. When I boot up a live os it basically creates a fresh environment with regard to input devices and video drivers. That's what I'm trying to obtain.

Comment: You do that by avoiding it altogether: no AMD modules, no NVidia modules, just kernel modules...  And these are extremely good at adapting to their environment! They're like mongrels: they'll eat anything, drink anything and ... well, whatever.  ;-) It just works! As long as you stay away from anything proprietary

Comment: Unfortunately for my needs (steam/games/3d), I need the proprietary drivers.

Comment: Then you sacrifice portability: you'll need one USB stick per computer; or one boot partition per computer, but that would be [an entirely new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I was hoping to have the best of both worlds (Portability & Performance) but I think my phrasing wasn't quite accurate. New question: http://askubuntu.com/q/668964/89202