# Ubuntu not installed on PC, but on pendrive

Tags: system-installation, hp, usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu on my flash USB drive. After installing, my laptop wanted a restart to use Ubuntu. But after I restarted it, it seems like nothing has happened. Ubuntu hasn't been installed.

But when I open my USB folder, I see so many files of Ubuntu.
So how can I install it permanently, with my USB's files?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview
follow this .its a webpage by which u can install ubuntu on your device i recommand to start the process fresh from the starting

Comment: You provided few specifics. Ubuntu is available in many products, and various releases, and using various installers (*selected by the ISO you download and thus use*). We don't know which you used, but some installers can be *tricked* to misbehave (*writing boot loader to wrong device, meaning it won't boot*) by how the ISO is written to thumb-drive (prior to install), but we have no details here either.  In recent years I've opted to use a *live* system with persistence instead of installing the system to thumb-drive.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you *trying* to install to your usb drive, ie a persistent usb drive (as per this Q&A) https://askubuntu.com/questions/793879/persistent-ubuntu-usb-drive , or are you trying use usb installation media to install Ubuntu on your laptop’s hard drive?

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure about the proper installation, try to reorder the bootloader drive inside your BIOS/UEFI
i'm not sure about the use-case but you can always use ubuntu-live